# Use tablet pc as make shift wacom pad

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing-tablet

I have a desktop that I do all my work and stuff and I also have a Dell Venue 11 Pro tablet with a stylus that I use for on the software development. I was wondering if it's possible to have Photoshop on my desktop but use the tablet as a drawing pad? I'm in the process of repairing an old poster and doing it all through a mouse would be so much more tedious. I don't feel like purchasing a wacom tablet or similar for just a single project when I already have tablet with a surprisingly decent pen for being a Dell.

I did thing about development some software to accomplish this, but the time to do that would out weigh the time to complete the process with a mouse, so I figured I'd ask is anyone as found a way to do this.

Comment: This type of hardware question would maybe be suitable for superuser.com